# Lower bounds on cardinality of a union of blocks in a design

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

Let $D$ be a $(v,k,\lambda)$-design (repeated blocks are allowed). I would like to get a lower bound on the cardinality of the union of $s$ blocks. A naive application of inclusion-exclusion gives $sk-\binom{k}{2}$ which is sometimes useful, but from the few examples I've worked out seems to be a severe underestimation of the true situation.

Has anyone treated this question before?

If it helps, we can progressively simplify to symmetric designs and then to finite projective planes (i.e. $\lambda=1$).

Answer (score 2):

I think a found a satisfactory answer. Using [Corradi's Lemma](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=OyrOOrTmlvwC&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=corradi%2527s+lemma&source=bl&ots=6GViNzUn4c&sig=Oqfl27w5eal8p1P405PnpAi1Oc4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZEiBUavOFMnWPPiJgZAD&ved=0CFoQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=corradi%2527s%2520lemma&f=false) I can show **for projective planes** ($\lambda=1$) that the cardinality is at least $\frac{k^{2}s}{k+s-1}$.